# Need to rotate a humanoid model about x axis

Tags: roblox

I am trying to rotate a humanoid model about x axis when it's in the air to create a superman like effect. I am able to achieve the rotation about y axis but every time I try to do it on x-axis it seems like something overrides it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you may know, it helps if you provide your code in roblox. As a gaming noob, I don't know the language, but people who do may find the question not helpful and they may downvote your question.

Comment: Shivam, it's possible you've got some animations on your Humanoid that are fighting with your X-axis changes. When you test, try deleting those animations from  the Player in the workspace.